# Is it possible to have a VM access the internet but not the local network?

Tags: windows, virtual-machines

I would have thought that this is a pretty common thing, but my search yielded no results. Maybe it is because I'm not versed enough in VM and their networking, to look for the right terms.

The idea is a to have a Windows-VM on a Windows-host system. The guest system should not be able to access the local network, but the internet.

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to ask this.

Comment: Of course it is possible with the proper network setup. You need a dedicated network for this, which is separated by the local network physically or with VLANs, and only routed to the internet.

Comment: "I would have thought that this is a pretty common thing" - yes, it is also the type of trivial setup a junior sysadmin does in his sleep. DMZ style setup or a VLAN that has no routing or switching to the internal networks re as simple as it gets. Given a total lack of those base knowledge - the better palce to ask is superuser.com

Comment: Thanks @TomTom, I'm just the programmer you would like to have the setup. My sysadmin told me that's not possible and I was surprised, as it's pretty easy on my home network to have a guest account that can only connect to the internet. What would I need to tell my admin to point him in the right direction?